# Advantages of Erlang over (something like) node.js?

Tags: comparison, erlang, node.js

I realize that they are different beast used to solve different problems, but I would like to ask for an enumerated list of advantages of Erlang over node.js (and vice-versa).  When would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Erlang is a language and a runtime. I'm assuming you wish a comparison of the erlang runtime with node.js

First I'll list the similarities:

- Both lend themselves to event driven programming.
- Both focus on highly asynchronous programming.

And then then the advantages Erlang has:

- Erlangs message passing abstracts the differences between local and distributed processes making distributed programming easier.
- Erlangs hot code loading allows for in place releases on running services without disrupting any current activity.
- Erlang has superior tools for packaging and deployment.
- Erlangs supervisor and gen_server behviors provide a superior framework for building extremely robust and fault tolerant systems.

Comment: Afaik node.js forces you to write event driven code where erlang only gives you the option, thus you can fall back to a different code style, when needed.

Comment: Hot loading is a hot topic in the node community, and we may see that as a possibility soon. There are ways to do it, using the existing V8 API, the question is mostly how to do it seamlessly.

Comment: What does each one of these offer that something like Common Lisp does not and cannot do?

Comment: Well I'm not an expert in Common Lisp so the answer could go either way. But I suspect that in Common Lisp you might have to implement the runtime bits that erlang builds into it's vm and stdlib and that make it especially robust in the face of failures.

Answer (score 11):

Erlang is 20 years old, and has been battle-tested many times. Uses all cores on your systems and makes clustering easy.

node.js is still very young, will only use one core per runtime.

And all what Jeremy Wall says.

Comment: what about now, its now 5 years , tell me now which one i should use.

Comment: I'm still a big fan of Erlang, and with Elixir on the landscape, the VM now has a language with the potential to become quite popular. The Phoenix Framework is fantastic, and ejabberd can embed Elixir modules natively in a quite elegant way.

Comment: I wouldn't want to take away from this comment at all, and I don't have a ton of experience with erlang. However it is worth mentioning that the quite small core libraries of nodejs are this young (streams, etc), but the much "bigger" part of it is V8, googles javascript engine. So the libraries have gone through a ton of iterations and are at this point considered quite stable, but the the main aspects of it are very rock solid because V8 is much older and much more battle tested.

Answer (score 4):

Don't discount the power of Erlang pattern matching. As much as I like JavaScript, this addictive language feature is simply not baked in. It also seems the JS community doesn't quite appreciate the no shared state paradigm. Finally, multi-instances to utilize multi-cores seems retrograde to me.